# How do I retrieve the primary key data from each table in an automated way?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a hash key using only certain columns that are the primary key for each table. I need to do this for 2500 tables. I am able to create a hash value using my code here:

```
SELECT 
    A.*, B.hash_key 
FROM 
    <TABLE_NAME> A 
CROSS APPLY
    (VALUES (HASHBYTES('md5', (SELECT A.* FOR JSON PATH)))) B (hash_key)
```

This creates a hash value based on all the columns in the table, but I want to do this with only the primary key columns in the table.

I am not sure if I can retrieve the actual data from the primary key columns using information schema or does that just grab the column names? The data is automatically inserted in my python script once the hash value is created, I am just not sure how to choose the PK columns in my code instead of all the columns

Comment: You should be able to use `WHERE field.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'` -- See [Table Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/table-constraints-transact-sql)

Comment: This feels like you're trying to solve something else. What do you want to accomplish in reality that needs hash of primary keys

Comment: This sounds like an XYProblem - however what you are asking is possible with a little DynamicSQL to built your query from the `sys.indexes, sys.columns, sys.tables` views

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example query here is how you might dynamically build your required SQL to display and pass just the PK columns to the hashbytes function:

```
select concat('select ',
    String_Agg(c.[name], ', '),
    ', hash_key
    from ',
    t.[name], '
    cross apply (values (hashbytes(''md5'', concat('''', ', 
    String_Agg(c.[name], ', '),
    '))))hk(hash_key);')
from sys.tables t
join sys.indexes i on i.object_id = t.object_id and i.is_primary_key = 1
join sys.index_columns ic on ic.object_id = t.object_id and ic.index_id = i.index_id
join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = ic.column_id
group by t.name
order by t.name;
```